# Applets. Why does paint method requires graphics as an argument

Tags: java, applet, awt

Why paint method requires graphics objects as an argument? Passing graphics get as an argument here.

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
```

Answer (score 1):

`paint` method requires `Graphics` as an argument because otherwise it would not know in what graphic context the drawing needs to be made.

An implementation of `paint` needs to perform its drawing in some context, i.e. make calls like `g.drawImage` etc. Without a `Graphics` parameter the `paint` would have to have some alternative way of getting hold of that `g` parameter, e.g. though some static method or a variable. This approach would be less explicit than providing the context as a method parameter.

Letting the caller decide what `Graphics` to pass to your `paint` method has an added benefit: the content of your applet can be captured for printing without any additional work on your part. The host of your applet simply passes a printer's graphic context to the same `print` method to get a printable image of your running applet.